# Correct syntax for working precision in functions version 12

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

I just recently updated from version 11.2 -> 12...there apparently are quite a few changes since 11.2. $\unicode{952}\unicode{960}$

One being how version >11.3 deal with numbers that approach zero.

To simulate a physical impulse one can use such an equation:

```
bump[t_] := 7 E^(-10 (t - 3)^2) - 3/2 E^(-10 (t - 6)^2) + 3 E^(-10 (t - 9)^2)
```

[image: plot]

Which looks like this plotted over time in 11.2 and 11.1 this didn't cause any issues for me, I use this function quite often for impulses in many systems.

Now however I am constantly getting an error that comes along with it:

[image: error]

After doing some duckduckgoing, I found in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195174/the-too-small-to-represent-as-a-normalized-machine-number-error-message) And with some more infos and what I thought would be a solution [at this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94996/machine-precision-near-zero-not-fulfilled)

One can simply increase the precision using

```
Exp[-900`20]
(*3.6678745841776872*10^-348*)
```

However as I try in all combinations of adding the higher precision or using Working Precision -> 20 I get error messages, or barring error messages in the functions themselves, I get the old General error message in the plot,

[image: errors]

When using NDSolve[] the system becomes stiff at a specific time and cannot be further calculated (which in prior versions was again, never an issue)

Example working code from 11.2 with error from v12 and NDSolve:

```
Plot[{θ[t] 10, ϕ'[t]} /. 
   NDSolve[{{{0.18884908961676594` Sin[θ[t]] + 
      0.0023324989011712697` θ''[
        t] == -0.000795` ArcTan[
        10.` θ'[t]] + 
      0.0920755` Cos[θ[t]] f[t] - 
      0.00016799999999999996` θ'[t] - 
      0.0004032497194086029` ϕ''[t], 
    0.0004032497194086029` ϕ''[t] == 
     0.0335` u[t] - 
      0.000039255383907286545` ϕ'[t] + 
      0.0004032497194086029` θ''[
        t]}, {θ[0] == 3.0915926535897933`, 
    θ'[0] == 0, ϕ[0] == 0, 
    ϕ'[0] == 0}} /. {u[t] -> 
    42.69342907334017` (-π + θ[t]) + 
     3.88853571287127` θ'[t] + 
     0.21937104569306368` ϕ'[t], 
   f[t] -> 3 E^(-10 (-9 + t)^2) - 3/2 E^(-10 (-6 + t)^2) + 
     7 E^(-10 (-3 + t)^2)}}, {θ[t], ϕ'[t]}, {t, 0, 
     14}] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 14}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> {θ, ϕ'}]
```

[image: error plot]

f[t] being where I would normally add my external forces, as my impulse function.

An attempt to add higher working precision to my bumpy function with error:

```
bumpy[t_] := 7 Exp[-10 (t - 3)^2`20 ] - 3/2 Exp[-10 (t - 6)^2`20 ] + 3 Exp[-10 (t - 9)^2`20]

(*Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "-10 (t-3)^2 `20)".*)
```

What is the correct way/syntax to write a function with increased precision for further use?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the code that produces errors?

Comment: Hi, yes gladly!, the image of the syntax error is already given with the last bit of code, bumpy[t_] under the attempt which gives the error in the image above it....and I will add an example where NDSolve fails as of version 12.

Comment: actually that code does not produce any errors on my machine, that's why I asked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If working with machine precision produces machine underflow/overflow errors, than you need to work with extended precision numbers. This means that your input cannot contain any machine precision numbers. One possibility is to use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize) to convert your ode into exact numbers:

```
ode = Flatten @ Rationalize[{{{0.18884908961676594` Sin[θ[t]] + 
      0.0023324989011712697` θ''[
        t] == -0.000795` ArcTan[
        10.` θ'[t]] + 
      0.0920755` Cos[θ[t]] f[t] - 
      0.00016799999999999996` θ'[t] - 
      0.0004032497194086029` ϕ''[t], 
    0.0004032497194086029` ϕ''[t] == 
     0.0335` u[t] - 
      0.000039255383907286545` ϕ'[t] + 
      0.0004032497194086029` θ''[
        t]}, {θ[0] == 3.0915926535897933`, 
    θ'[0] == 0, ϕ[0] == 0, 
    ϕ'[0] == 0}} /. {u[t] -> 
    42.69342907334017` (-π + θ[t]) + 
     3.88853571287127` θ'[t] + 
     0.21937104569306368` ϕ'[t], 
   f[t] -> 3 E^(-10 (-9 + t)^2) - 3/2 E^(-10 (-6 + t)^2) + 
     7 E^(-10 (-3 + t)^2)}}, 0];
ode //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\frac{3559064 \theta ''(t)}{1525858811}+\frac{28353452 \sin (\theta
>    (t))}{150138145}=-\frac{36921618901 \theta '(t)}{219771541077381}-\frac{159 \tan
>    ^{-1}\left(10 \theta '(t)\right)}{200000}+\frac{184151 \left(3 e^{-10
>    (t-9)^2}-\frac{3}{2} e^{-10 (t-6)^2}+7 e^{-10 (t-3)^2}\right) \cos (\theta
>    (t))}{2000000}-\frac{4587948 \phi ''(t)}{11377436311},\frac{4587948 \phi
>    ''(t)}{11377436311}=\frac{4587948 \theta ''(t)}{11377436311}+\frac{67
>    \left(\frac{139127231 \theta '(t)}{35778823}+\frac{307971783 (\theta (t)-\pi
>    )}{7213564}+\frac{79283177 \phi '(t)}{361411310}\right)}{2000}-\frac{183308 \phi
>    '(t)}{4669626985},\theta (0)=\frac{118092245}{38197867},\theta '(0)=0,\phi (0)=0,\phi
>    '(0)=0\right\}$

Now, there are no machine numbers polluting your equations. So, use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) with a [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision) option:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[ode, {θ[t], ϕ'[t]}, {t, 0, 14}, WorkingPrecision->20];
```

> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating 82222031699886430677801536777088869542973260569651374914500 E^1260 π.
>
> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating 82222031699886430677801536777088869542973260569651374914500 E^1260 π.
>
> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating 82222031699886430677801536777088869542973260569651374914500 E^1260 π.
>
> General::stop: Further output of N::meprec will be suppressed during this calculation.

Visualization:

```
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 14}]
```

[image]